# How to register SmtpClient with Unity Container?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am using .Net SmtpClient class for sending email. The configuration for smtp is stored in config file. You can use the application or machine configuration files to specify default host, port, and credentials values for all SmtpClient objects. The default constructor will read all the values from configuration file.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    <configuration>
      <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
          <smtp deliveryMethod="network">
            <network
              host="localhost"
              port="25"
              defaultCredentials="true"
            />
          </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
      </system.net>
    </configuration>
```

Here is my interface and class that's using SmtpClient

```
    public interface IEmail:IDisposable
    {
         void Send(string[] to)
    }


    public class SmtpEmail : IEmail
    {
        private bool _disposed = false;
        private SmtpClient _client = null;

        public SmtpEmail(SmtpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }
        public void Send(string[] to)
        {
            using (MailMessage message = GetEmailMessage())
            {
                foreach (string email in to)
                {
                    message.To.Add(email);
                }               

                _client.Send(message);               
            }
        }       

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);

            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (_client != null)
                    {
                        _client.Dispose();
                        _disposed = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**I want to dispose the SmtpClient as soon we are done sending email. Here how I'm calling it using ServiceLocator**

```
 using(var emailClient = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEmail>())
 {
     emailClient.Send(new string[] { "someone@domain.com"};
 }
```

Here is how I'm registering with Unity

```
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<SmtpClient,SmtpClient>();
        container.RegisterType<IEmail, SmtpEmail>();

        UnityServiceLocator locator = new UnityServiceLocator(container);
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);
```

However I am getting error

> {"Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   \"MyFramework.Core.Email.IEmail\", name = \"(none)\".\r\nException
>   occurred while: while resolving.\r\nException is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The type String cannot be constructed. You
>   must configure the container to supply this
>   value.\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\nAt the
>   time of the exception, the container was:\r\n\r\n  Resolving
>   MyFramework.Core.Email.SmtpEmail,(none) (mapped from
>   MyFramework.Core.Email.IEmail, (none))\r\n  Resolving parameter
>   \"client\" of constructor
>   MyFramework.Core.Email.SmtpEmail(System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
>   client)\r\n    Resolving System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient,(none)\r\n
>   Resolving parameter \"host\" of constructor
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(System.String host, System.Int32 port)\r\n 
>   Resolving System.String,(none)\r\n"}

Question
How do I register SmtpClient with Unity so that SmtpClient can use its default constructor and also Unity can create new instance every time.

Answer (score -1):

Unity container tries to create `SmtpEmail` class object. It has [3 constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx), and unity selects the one with [the most amount of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253149/unity-not-using-the-default-constructor-of-the-class):

```
public SmtpClient(
    string host,
    int port
)
```

So, you need to specifify to select consttructor wiuthout parameters:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<SmtpClient>(new InjectionConstructor());
container.RegisterType<IEmail, SmtpEmail>();
```

Comment: @LP13 can you accept this answer, or I should add some comments?

Comment: Do we have to new up the SmtpClient or is it recommended to inject it via DI?