# Prism 7 throws ResolutionFailedException: No public constructor available for type (Interface)

Tags: mvvm, unity-container, prism, constructor-injection, prism-7

I'm devolping a WPF application, using Prism 7.2. I have a module, which implements the `IModule` interface, where I register the views and viewmodels in the `RegisterTypes` method, e.g.:

```
containerRegistry.Register<IPanelOptimizationViewModel, PanelOptimizationViewModel>();
```

The problem arises when I try to resolve the implementation:

```
var vm = containerProvider.Resolve<IPanelOptimizationViewModel>();
```

whereupon I get the following **Unity.ResolutionFailedException**:
        'Resolution failed with error: No public constructor is available for type 
        XXX.Infrastructure.Interfaces.IView.'

The `PanelOptimizationViewModel` class derives from a base class:

```
public class PanelOptimizationViewModel : ViewModelBase, IPanelOptimizationViewModel
{
     public PanelOptimizationViewModel(IPanelOptimizationView view, IPanelOptimizationInputViewModel inpVM) : base(view)
}
```

and the `ViewModelBase` looks like this:

```
 public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase, IViewModel
 {
     public IView View { get; set; }

     public ViewModelBase(IView view)
     {
         View = view;
         View.ViewModel = this;
     }
 }
```

The interfaces `IView` and `IViewModel` are defined in a common Infrastructure project. They are not registered anywhere in the container, but if I remove the `IPanelOptimizationInputViewModel` parameter, no runtime exception is thrown - leading me to think that I don't need to do this, either.

As far as I have been able to understand, the `Unity.Container` will use the "most parameterized" constructor (see [Unity not using the default constructor of the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253149/unity-not-using-the-default-constructor-of-the-class)), but I cannot provide a parameter in the Register method to specify this, as one apparently could before (pre Prism 7's container abstraction), with the RegisterType method.

How to solve this? Is there an overload of the Prism.Ioc.IContainerRegistry.Register method that allows me to set up the registration for constructor injection?

Should I work directly with the Unity container?

Basically, I am trying to inject a child view's viewmodel into the constructor of my "main" viewmodel, but this does not go well as long as the wrong constructor is called on the base class, with the wrong set of parameters... (if that is what is happening).

Needless to say, all child views and viewmodels have been registered in the RegisterTypes method in the module.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Resolving which type exactly do you get the `ResolutionFailedException`? `IPanelOptimizationViewModel`, `IPanelOptimizationInputViewModel ` or something else?

Comment: I try to resolve `IPanelOptimizationViewModel`. The **Unity.ResolutionFailedException** is thrown by `PopupWindowAction` class in `Prism.Interactivity`, if that gives any additional information as to what causes this problem

Comment: I mean - resolving `IPanelOptimizationViewModel` includes resolving, for example, `IPanelOptimizationInputViewModel`, and it's important which one of these `Resolve`s throws. You wrote that removing the dependency on `IPanelOptimizationInputViewModel` removes the exception, so it seems natural that that one or one of its dependencies causes the exception.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. I found the issue. Instead of defining a variable of type `IPanelOptimizationInputView` in the constructor to the `IPanelOptimizationViewModel`, I had defined one of type `IView`. Problem solved. Thanks for the help, anyways, @Haukinger

Answer (score 0):

> Should I work directly with the Unity container?

Yes, you can evade Prism's "abstraction" of the container by calling the `GetContainer()` extension method (for your container).

```
containerRegistry.GetContainer() // here you get a plain IUnityContainer
                 .RegisterType( ... );
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I tried that after I wrote the original question. It doesn't seem to solve the problem, though. I also tried to register the `IView`interface in the `RegisterTypes` method in the `App.xaml.cs`, but to no avail...